# Plotly: manual fillcolor for boxplot

Tags: r, plotly

I've a boxplot, but I want to use manual colors for the fill of eachone.

[image]

**code:**

```
p <- plot_ly(tvs, x = ~ecommerce, y = ~precio_actual, color = ~ecommerce, type = "box") %>%
  layout(boxmode = "group")

p
```

**colors I need to use:**

```
ecommerce_colors <- c("lacuracao" = "#ffda33","ripley" = "#802D69","falabella" = "#BED800",
                      'wong' = "red", "tottus" = "#fa3e14")
```

Comment: assuming ecommerce is your factor by which to color, you can also add the 'colors' argument (use both 'color' and 'colors' arguments in plot_ly statement) and set 'colors' to a vector containing your custom colors...for example: ecommerce_colors <- c("#ffda33", "#802D69", "#BED800", "red", "#fa3e14")...ordered depending on data...will that work?

Comment: @Ben, yes that did work. Was confused about color and colours, but having both is what I needed. Ty.