# How to fill box plots with a user-defined color in R plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

This question is obviously a replicate from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879211/plotly-manual-fillcolor-for-boxplot#_=_).

However I could not apply the solution given in the comments, hence my question.

I want to use user-defined colors to fill box plots with plotly.

In the following code I would expect the boxes to be filled respectively with red and blue, but they keep the default colors.

```
library(plotly)

d1 <- data.frame(val = rnorm(n=1000), type=1)
d2 <- data.frame(val = rnorm(n=1000), type=2)
col1 <- "red"
col2 <- "blue"

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = d1, y = ~val, type="box", colors=col1) %>%
  add_trace(data = d2, y = ~val, type="box", colors=col2)
```

I have managed to change the lines' and markers' colors, but not the fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
plot_ly(colors=c(col1, col2)) %>%
  add_trace(data = d1, y = ~val, type="box", color=I(col1)) %>%
  add_trace(data = d2, y = ~val, type="box", color=I(col2))
```

[image]

Comment: I was using hex-coded colors, and that worked as well. Easy mistake is to confuse "colors" with "color" in the argument. Thank you MrFlick and Onyambu!

Answer (score 2):

Use the parameter `fillcolor`

```
plot_ly() %>%
    add_trace(data = d1, y = ~val, type = "box", fillcolor = col1) %>%
    add_trace(data = d2, y = ~val, type = "box", fillcolor = col2)
```

[image]